# How can I add file permission via Woocommerce API?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I want to grant access an order to a file via REST API. I couldn't find anything about file permissions.

There is a function for that;

```
wc_downloadable_file_permission( $download_id, $product_id, $order );
```

Can we do the same with Woocommerce REST API?